# c# nunit TestCaseSource can't provide unique test data for each test run

Tags: c#, nunit

I am using nunit `TestCase` and `TestCaseSource` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497638/visual-studio-c-sharp-unit-testing-run-unit-test-with-varied-multiple-test-ini) and have the following question about `TestCaseSource`. When the test code is:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("TestData")]
void Test1(string uniqueId){...}

private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestData()
{
    string uniqueId = "myString";         
    yield return new TestCaseData(uniqueId);
}
```

then the `TestCaseSource` works and the `Test1` runs with the uniqueId variable, but when the test code is:

```
private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestData()
{
    string uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);
    yield return new TestCaseData(uniqueId);
}
```

then while the `TestCaseSource` appears to return fine, the `Test1` doesn't run. Please comment.

Comment: Did you debug this? Are you sure your `TestData`-method actually returns a `TestCaseData`? Try to debug what `uinquetId` i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using NUnit's random class should solve this problem.

This issue is that the test name is created using the parameter to TestCaseData. In some situations (e.g. if you're using the VS Test Adapter) TestCaseSources are enumerated more than once. If a test of the same name can't be found again - things go wrong. This is why manually setting the name fixes the issue.

If you use the NUnit random class, then the random value is seeded and repeatable (which is probably generally a good idea for any test using random data anyway!)

Try this:

```
private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestData()
{
    string uniqueId = TestContext.CurrentContext.Random.NextGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);
    yield return new TestCaseData(uniqueId);
}
```

Note that the `NextGuid()` method is part of NUnit 3.8, which will be released towards the end of the month. For now, you can get a package from the MyGet feed, rather than NuGet: https://www.myget.org/F/nunit/api/v2

Answer (score 0):

It works if I add a `.SetName("myName")` as follows:

```
private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestData()
{
    string uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);
    yield return new TestCaseData(uniqueId)
    .SetName("myTest");
}
```