# How do you pass a c# record into an NUnit test with TestCaseSource?

Tags: c#, parameters, nunit, record

In this sample using nunit v3.13.3 I expect two tests to be run

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(_cases))]
public void MethodInTestProject(RecordParameter recordParameter)
{
    Assert.Pass();
}

private static readonly object[] _cases = new object[]
{
    new object?[]
    {
        null,
    },
    new object?[]
    {
        new RecordParameter(Guid.NewGuid()),
    },
};

public record RecordParameter(Guid StoreId);
```

When debugging only the first case is passed into MethodInTestProject.  In test explorer I get the following output

```
 MethodInTestProject(RecordParameter { StoreId = 71cda514-3e76-4829-a244-1f39cd4a2532 })
   Source:MyTests.cs line 228
```

I have other examples of passing in classes, value types, etc in parameters without any errors.  Is there a specific way to pass c# records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing @Charlie 's answer I discovered the record parameter didn't have anything to do with the issue.  The issue is related to the `Guid.NewGuid()` portion of the parameter.  If that is changed to `Guid.Parse("edce8430-e40e-440c-9b70-e5684eeac1e1")` then the test runs fine.

Details on why this works are available here [c# nunit TestCaseSource can't provide unique test data for each test run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635267/c-sharp-nunit-testcasesource-cant-provide-unique-test-data-for-each-test-run)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a source which consists of an array of object arrays. Although
technically permissible, this gives NUnit almost no Type information to use when interpreting the source. Making the second level array nullable complicates things further. That array represents the collected arguments to a method and can't be null. In your case, you could eliminate one level since the method only takes a single argument.

However, a better approach would be to use `TestCaseData`, the NUnit class which is designed to hold the information about a test case. Something like this...

```cs
private static readonly TestCaseData[] _cases = new []
{
    new TestCaseData(null), // Assuming you want null passed to the method
    new TestCaseData(new RecordParameter(Guid.NewGuid()))
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it got me to the correct solution.  I didn't know there was an issue using random data with TestCaseSource